# How to print/press '@' using keybd_event function?

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard-events, keystroke

To press 'a' code is

```
keybd_event(VkKeyScan(64),0,0,0);
```

Releasing key code is

```
keybd_event(VkKeyScan(64),0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
```

For pressing '@' i need combination of two key - SHIFT & 2 , but i don't know how.

keybd_event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: What OS are you using?  And can you supply the code that you used to what Hurzelchen suggested?

Comment: Windows 7 and i am currently working on Hurzelchen code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Press Shift
2. Press 2
3. Release 2
4. Release Shift

**Addendum**

I just checked my own code where I did the same thing... `keybd_event` is deprecated (as stated on the site you linked), you should use `SendInput` instead.

This are my two functions to send the key press and release:

```
void sendKeyDown(unsigned char keyCode)
{
    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;

    input.ki.wVk = keyCode;
    input.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    input.ki.time = 0;
    input.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
}

void sendKeyUp(unsigned char keyCode)
{
    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;

    input.ki.wVk = keyCode;
    input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    input.ki.time = 0;
    input.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

And this should then give you an `@`:

```
sendKeyDown(VK_SHIFT);
sendKeyDown(0x32);
sendKeyUp(0x32);
sendKeyUp(VK_SHIFT);
```

Please check the `0x32`, I can't reliably test it at the moment to be the key `2`.

Comment: how is the output different than what we would expect?

Comment: Output is p2 , don't know how.

Comment: just updated my question with a code snipped I used to send key strokes to an application.

Comment: Thank you Hurzelchen ('@') is now printing. This will help me in my program.